# angular: From translation file in i18n of ngx-translate, how can I get all keys?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using **Angular 11** and I need how to get all the keys of json file of the selected language using **ngx-translate-core** library.

I need it because I need to filter the keys for the current page loaded.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

//1- inject 'TranslateService' in the 'constructor' of the Component that
//you want to call the keys

```
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
```

//2- in 'ngOnInit'

```
 this.translate.getTranslation(this.translate.currentLang)
.subscribe(transAsJson => {
  let allKeysAsString = Object.keys(transAsJson);
  console.log(allKeysAsString)
});
```

that will get you all the keys for the current language but not the complex keys for sub-objects in the JSON you will have to check if the value of the key is complex or not .. for an example if the JSON file value for the current language is

{ "first": "valuee", "second": "valuee", "FirstSub": { "FirstSub_first": "valuee", "FirstSub_second": "valuee" } }

the result should be like

```
['first', 'second', 'FirstSub']
```